# Clear all Values field in Power Pivot Table Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear all **Values** field in my power pivot table

```
 Sub RemoveValueFields()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim df As PivotField

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Invoices")

    'remove calculated fields first,
    'if any exist
    For Each pf In pt.CalculatedFields
        For Each df In pt.DataFields
          If df.SourceName = pf.Name Then
            With df
              .Parent.PivotItems(.Name) _
                .Visible = False
            End With
            Exit For
                  End If
Next df
    Next pf

    For Each pf In pt.DataFields
      pf.Orientation = xlHidden 'I get an error here Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class
    Next pf

 End Sub
```

I have found this answer here for **column** fields: [How to remove all column fields in a Pivot Table ( Power Pivot)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759538/how-to-remove-all-column-fields-in-a-pivot-table-power-pivot)
but am not sure how I would adapt this to Values Fields...

Comment: I recreated your scenario and have to report that the code executed as expected and removed all datafields.  Try looking for other factors that might be influencing your situation.  Is the pivot alone on its worksheet?  If not, try isolating it and running your code again.  Is there any other formatting, or are other formulas referencing fields in this pivot?  Things of this nature may be causing the trouble.